# Вычисление процентов

Tags: c#

Скажите, я вот писал такую программу на VB.NET, и она у меня получалась, а вот на C# не могу сделать. Прочитал первую книгу по C# там не было примера калькулятора :(.

```
Label4.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) * Val(TextBox2.Text) / 100 * Val(TextBox3.Text)
```

А вот как реализовать подобное на C# не понимаю...

Comment: Значит вы не писали такую программу а тупо переписали с книги, надо понимать разницу :)

Comment: Нет.. я её писал сам. Просто в первой книге по C# не было подобного примера, а мне срочно понадобилось написать подобную программу. Думаю вы поняли меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Получение доступа к свойству с текстом такое же: `TextBox1.Text`
2. Чтобы распарсить текстовое значение в число: `double.Parse(TextBox1.Text)` (или какой нужен тип)
3. Получившееся нужно привести к строке: `(...).ToString()`

Получаем:
`Label4.Text = (double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * double.Parse(TextBox2.Text) / 100 * double.Parse(TextBox3.Text)).ToString()`

Comment: Мда... как всё запутанно в этом языке... Спасибо за ответ, помогло.

Comment: А вот например если я ввожу в поле "проценты"(TextBox2) к примеру 0.7, то программа выдает ошибку.

Comment: Не знаком с проблемой, но что будет, если ввести 0,7 (через запятую)?

Comment: Нет 0.7 точка. и вот такая ошибка

"Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Comment: Просто в русской локали такие числа пишутся через запятую, а не через точку. Если хочется через точку, можно заменить точку на запятую с помощью string.Replace. Или более правильно - можно использовать NumberFormatInfo.

Comment: а еще лучше double.TryParse()